# Is there something like the Wubi installer for Linux Mint?

Tags: installation, linux-mint, wubi

I want to use Linux Mint. I would like to know if there is something like the Wubi installer for Linux Mint? I searched on the Linux Mint website, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that easily. You'll need an extra ubuntu or lubuntu ISO image. Extract Wubi.exe from the ISO file and put the ISO file and the Wubi.exe at drive C. Then run Wubi and install Ubuntu.

After it finishes installation don't restart your computer. Goto `C://Ubuntu/install/boot`, then replace these 3 files:
`VMLINUZ` `INITRD.LZ` `MD5SUM` with the same files from MINT (or any othr Linux  you want to install) ISO file (look inside `CASPER` folder). Lastly replace the `installation.iso` file with your `MINT.ISO` file.

Now restart your computer and install MINT instead of Ubuntu

Watch this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jtzm4DOdrKw

A Step by Step Guide to install any linux distro inside Windows using WUBI

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a Wubi for Linux Mint. And it works- at least on my Windows XP and with Linux Mint 15.

You will need the `.iso` and a program like Power ISO. You just open the `.iso` file with Power ISO and search for `mint4win.exe`. Open that as admin and the rest is the same as with Wubi.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, someone actually used that thing!

I would not expect there to be. Ubuntu markets itself for the new Linux user and takes every opportunity to make the switch easier. Mint is not Ubuntu, they take what they like of the Ubuntu fork and make the rest less Ubuntu. I know of no TP Wubi...

Also, even with Wubi it is going away. Partially because [it does not work](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) with new PCs.

> Wubi does not work on any new PC with the Windows 8 logo or using UEFI
>   firmware. Please use a 64-bit flavour of Ubuntu, installed directly to
>   its own partition instead. For more information see
>   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  If you upgraded to Windows 8
>   and are using BIOS firmware, Wubi does work, but do not enable
>   hybrid-sleep on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution on my own, [you can find here](https://github.com/antonio-petricca/buddy-linux) my project.